# Где, каким образом получить результат ответа на запрос в Yii2 и отправить его на емэйл?

Tags: php, yii2, response

Где, каким образом получить результат ответа на запрос, отправляемый таинственными алгоритмами Yii2 после нажатия на кнопку страницы, код которой ниже, и отправить этот результат на емэйл, который укажу при отправке?
документацию смотрю, но зацепку найти пока не удается. Или поясните хотя бы почему вардамп пустой. [Текст документации](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/runtime-responses) говорит о том, что искомое должно быть тут: Yii::$app->response->content. Однако там его нет. 
Страницу формы `views/contact/index.php` дополнил (есть небольшой дубляж по элементам - это себе для обучения):

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\bootstrap4\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\ContactSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Контакты';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>

<div class="contact-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Добавить контакт', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>

    <?php $LetterInsertion = GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'emptyText' => 'По указанным параметрам сотрудник не найден.',
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

//            'contact_id',
            'last_name',
            'first_name',
            'middle_name',
            'internal_phone',
            'mobile_phone',
            'email_address:email',

//                ['class' => 'app\components\MyActionColumn',
//                    'template' => '{view} {update} {delete}',
//                ],
        ],
    ]);
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $session['LetterInsertion'] = $LetterInsertion;
    ?>
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'contact-search']); ?>
    <?= $LetterInsertion ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Найти', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    <?= Html::a('Отменить фильтр', ['index'], ['class' => 'btn btn-outline-primary']); ?>
    <?= Html::resetButton('Сбросить', ['class' => 'btn btn-outline-secondary', 'onclick' => 'window.location.replace("index.php?r=contact");']) ?>
    </p>

    <?php if (Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('contactFormSubmitted')): ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            Сообщение 1 (файл views/contact/index.php)
        </div>

        <p>
            <?php if (Yii::$app->mailer->useFileTransport): ?>
                Сообщение 2 (файл views/contact/index.php)
                <code><?= Yii::getAlias(Yii::$app->mailer->fileTransportPath) ?></code>.
                <code>useFileTransport</code> property of the <code>mail</code>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </p>

    <?php else: ?>
    <p>Сообщение 3 (файл views/contact/index.php)</p>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">

            <?= $form->field($searchModel, 'email_address')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'form-control inputNotNull'])->label('Введите Email получателя: ');
            ?>

            <div class="form-group">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Отправить контакты', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'send-to-email-button']) ?>
                <?= Html::a('Отправить контакты', ['contact'], ['class' => 'btn btn-outline-primary']); ?>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <p>
        <?= Html::label('отправить контакты на') ?>
        <?= Html::input('text', 'send_to', 'email адресата') ?>
        <?= Html::submitButton('отправить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </p>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

`var_dump(Yii::$app->response->content)` при выдаче искомых позиций в количестве нескольких штук получается такой:

```
/var/www/eg/phbook_basic/views/contact/index.php:53:null
```

Comment: похоже, самых полезных на ресурсе участников хватает только на то, чтобы поставить минус )

Comment: Ваш вопрос непонятен - какой GET запрос, на какую почту вы пытаетесь отправить, какими средствами, чтобы пробовали кроме базового var_dump, читали ли документацию? Что именно вы пытаетесь достичь с вышеприведенным кодом? Как он связан с вашим вопросом?

Comment: Если вы делаете GET запрос к серверу, значит и ищите его на сервере в action. Откуда можете и выслать мейл. Что вы хотите на фронте показать не совсем ясно. Content формируется из данных что вы передадите в рендер функцию. Если вы в action ничего не передали, значит и в контент будет пусто. Еще раз - вам надо работать с контролером, там получить данные, обработать их и выслать письмо. Потом можете вернуть на фронт сообщение о статусе высылки письма.

Comment: @SimplyOne, а не понимаю чего вы пытаетесь достичь. У сервера доступ к ответу не будет, только к запросу, так как ответ будет меняться прокладками и много еще чем (включая веб-сервером). Напишите вашу конечную цель более простыми словами.

Comment: БД не отвечает на GET-запрос, как это понимать вообще?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov так как мне нужно отправить на почту отфильтрованные контакты, то логично сначала получить то, что отправлять - ответ бд на запрос, который, согласно документации, сохраняется в content: yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/runtime-responses Но ваш ответ озадачивает. на мой взгляд он, вероятно, сходится с наблюдением, но расходится с текстом по ссылке

Comment: @SimplyOne вам выше Moonvvell уже посоветовал где получать данные контактов для отсылки и делать отсылку почты - в методе контроллера. У вас выше код вьюшки, шаблона, в котором делать это не корректно - этот шаблон для вывода HTML, а не для бизнес-логики. Да, данные там есть, но они там чисто для показа пользователю.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov т.е. вы считаете, что если те же данные запросить в контроллере, то они окажутся там, где я их не вижу при своем запросе?

Comment: @Moonvvell обнаружил, что я несколько запутался в запросах. если поверхностно, то, как понял, get-запрос приводит к sql-запросу. и вот ответ БД с перечнем контактов нужно отправить почтой. можете пояснить где-как получить этот ответ для для дальнейшей отправки?

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть контроллер с каким-то action.

```
public function actionSendData()
{
    // Получаете данные из базы или еще откуда то (dataProvider etc.)
    $data = DbModel::findAll();
    // $htmlTemplate - темплейт вашего письма. Работает так же как при рендере страницы обычной.
    $mail = \Yii::$app->mailer->compose(['html' => $htmlTemplate], ['data' => $data]);
    $mail->send();
}
```

Скажу сразу - не совсем понимаю какие данные вы хотите отправлять. Поэтому просто описал как получение данных. Если это данные из `dataProvider` то вот дока по нему [Дата провайдер](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-data-providers).
Дока по использованию мейлера в Yii2 - [Тут](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-mailing).
И как по мне у Yii2 довольно понятная документация поэтому прочитайте еще раз. Там расписан процесс как работает MVC в фреймворке. [Тык](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-overview)

Comment: буду признателен, если поясните как вы понимаете общую схему взаимодействия компонентов MVC, на которую дали ссылку. видел ее не раз, но никак не пойму ее практической пользы, какие шаги она может подсказать.. в частности, как вы расшифровываете подписи с цифрами 0, 1, 1:1, двумя точками и звездочкой на линиях, соединяющих компоненты?

Comment: @SimplyOne пожалуйста прочитайте общий принцип MVC, можно даже на той же википедии.  Схема же читается как, например, отношения в базе данных - 0..* ноль к множеству, 1:1 - один к одному. Что значит конкретный элемент может иметь от нуля до множества связей с другим элементом. На схеме видно что входной скрипт может иметь 1 приложение, которое в свою очередь может иметь от 1 до бесконечности контролером. Так же приложение может иметь от 0 до бесконечности компонентов приложения и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем примере вообще не вижу работы с формой. Не понимаю с чего Вам вообще что-то должно приходить в таком случае. Возможно, я чего-то не знаю конечно. Но лично я бы сделал примерно так - создал модель формы. В ней описал поле в которое будет приходить нужный контент. Там же можно описать все необходимые проверки и отправку на email.

```php
<?php

namespace app\models\forms;

class myForm extends Model {
    public $content;
     public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['content'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }
    public function sendMail() {
        //тут отправка на почту
    }
}
```

Далее в `view`-файле делаете отображение формы

```php
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\forms\myForm */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\ContactSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;

$this->title = 'Контакты';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

$form = ActiveForm::begin();
?>
<div class="contact-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Добавить контакт', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>

    <!-- Тут можно поместить контент внутрь поля myForm->content двумя способами -->
    <!-- Самому создать `div` с `id` и `name` таким же как формирует `Yii2::ActiveForm` при выводе `$form->field` (в теории должно сработать, но не проверял) -->
    <!-- Либо создать `hidden` поле через `$form->field` и туда с помощью `javascript` по событию `formSubmit` передать содержимое страницы которое должно быть отправлено -->
    <div id="myform-content" name="myForm[content]">
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'emptyText' => 'По указанным параметрам сотрудник не найден.',
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'last_name',
            'first_name',
            'middle_name',
            'internal_phone',
            'mobile_phone',
            'email_address:email',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>

    <p>
        <?= Html::submitButton('Найти', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?= Html::resetButton('Сбросить', ['class' => 'btn btn-outline-secondary', 'onclick' => 'window.location.replace("index.php?r=contact");']) ?>
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
ActiveForm::end();
?>
```

В контроллере же в методе куда ведет `action` формы (пусть будет `my/create`) сделал бы следующее

```php
<?php

namespace app\controllers;
use yii\web\Controller;
class myController extends Controller {
    public function actionCreate() {
        $model = new myForm();
        if (\Yii::$app->request->isPost && count(\Yii::$app->request->post()) > 0 &&  $model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
             //Отправляем почту
             $myForm->sendMail()
             //Выводим отдельную страницу или куда-то перенаправляем               
         }
                
    }

}
```

Comment: phpBear, спасибо за ваши усилия. разбираюсь. поправил-дополнил view в вопросе. можете объяснить, почему `$LetterInsertion` (GridView), при включении его в ActiveForm (`<?= $LetterInsertion` поменял на `<?php $LetterInsertion` и, фактически, срабатывает его копия в ActiveForm ниже по коду), приходит в нерабочее состояние (сбрасывает строку, введенную в поле)? в вашем коде практически то же предложение. 
Рассчитываю, что кнопка сабмит отправит форму с контентом на почту (видимо, контент еще придется вставить в скрытое поле). Можно ли это сделать в рамках такого подхода?